# how long should I wait to leave a company in good for after getting a bonus

Tags: ethics

The question sums it up. I’m torn, about leaving my company and I don’t know how to approach it. currently I’m working as an electrician I just sat for my license, and passed. I got a small raise and a bonus about a month ago. But as of right now I see so many better opportunities and better paying jobs in a different scenery. To be specific positions to develop a specialty. So it’s not just hopping from one contractor to the next doing the same thing.

-how long should I wait to have good form and leave with my head held high so to speak about my ethics.(he didn’t pay for my school I did)

-should I offer to give the bonus back? If I left in a matter of a month or two?

-it’s more of a matter of better opportunities versus mistreatment which makes it harder.

Comment: You should wait until the bonus check clears in your bank account. That's how long you should wait. A bonus is for past work, not future work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I accept a raise when I am planning on leaving the company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27340/should-i-accept-a-raise-when-i-am-planning-on-leaving-the-company)

Answer (score 7):

Receiving a raise or bonus has nothing to do with when you leave a job.  The point of giving a bonus, to the employee, is to get you to think “there’s more where that came from” and make you feel like your position is a good deal.

If it’s not, and you can get offers for significantly better jobs (for whatever your definition of better is) then there is no professional expectation holding you in a job.

In no circumstance would you ever pay back a bonus (unless that’s dictated by contract for whatever reason).

Feel free and talk about things you want out of your role with your current employer to see if they can be accommodated.  But while loyalty is admirable, sacrificing your own career for it goes past loyalty to foolishness.

Answer (score 5):

A company *promises* a future bonus in order for you to stay for some time and do a good job. They *pay* a bonus to keep their promises and reward you for good *past* work. So there is no reason at all to return a bonus. Make sure it’s legally yours (paid into your bank account, and past the date it was due)

Your “punishment” for leaving will be that you don’t get the next bonus. If that’s fine, you leave.